# QT-Wallet not sync properly for altcoin

Tags: altcoin, altcoin-development

I tried to create altcoin using litecoin source code. I am able to generate genesis block for same. After setup on ubuntu VPS qt wallet connect to server and disconnect within seconds. Please help me to get out of this.

Here is log

trying connection xx.xx.xx.xx:9293 lastseen=113.8hrs
connected xx.xx.xx.xx:9293
send version message: version 70001, blocks=0, us=0.0.0.0:0, them=xx.xx.xx.xx:9293, peer=xx.xx.xx.xx:9293
disconnecting node xx.xx.xx.xx:29293

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this. Just need to check your VPS connections and its configuration. Make sure socket handshake is proper it resolve my issue.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! You can help this site by marking answers as accepted if they are correct and address the question.